# Querying a database and storing into a data structure in Python

Tags: python, database, pandas, querying

I haven't been able to find much on this topic, so I would really like some help with the actual code to achieve this task. Preferably, use Pandas for the data structure and Python for the language. Assume a list of first names(Sally, Mike, etc) is inputted and you want to query this list from a database of first and last names(Sally Smith, Mike Miller, etc). Based upon last names already given, we want to modify this text file to only include the first names that are present in the other database.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to your input?  This sounds like a network programming task...

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include information regarding what your input looks like... I assume that you want to load a Pandas dataframe but then query that dataframe based on some sort of list.  Please supply info...

Comment: explain in more, what you want  exactly?

Comment: It sounds like the user wants to query based on keys and values

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants to basically filter out the list of first names so that he can toss any first names that are not present in the list of first and last names.

Comment: Warship's recent comment is completely correct

Answer (score 1):

Without information about the type of DB you are using, I'm assuming it accepts SQL queries and you can connect from Python.

If those two conditions are satisfied, I would suggest trying Pandas' built-in query:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html